# WinRT - TCP clients?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

I am building an IRC client in the new WinRT `(.NET 4.5`) framework for Windows 8 Metro applications.

However, I have some issues. I've already figured out that I need to use a `StreamSocket` to read TCP data, but I may be doing something wrong.

The reason I believe this is because I am not receiving any data.

Below you see my code. I haven't been able to find any code samples on the web regarding this.

```
class IRCClient
{
    private StreamSocket tcpClient;
    public string Server = "holmes.freenode.net";
    public int Port = 6665;

    public IRCClient()
    {
        tcpClient = new StreamSocket();
    }

    public async void Connect()
    {
        await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(
                         new Windows.Networking.HostName(Server), 
                         Port.ToString(), 
                         SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

        DataReader reader = new DataReader(tcpClient.InputStream);
        string data = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(data);            
    }
}
```

Data is always an empty string following that code. Furthermore, UnconsumedBufferLength always returns 0.

How come?

Comment: random thought; have you tried the async methods? maybe they want to use async?

Comment: Yes, nothing is received yet by the time the connection is made.  You are going to have to call ReadAsync() on the InputStream.

Comment: Sorry, just a wild ass guess, but isn't IRC requires multicast UDP connectivity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell the `DataReader` to read bytes from the stream before you interpret them (`ReadString` just interprets the bytes already read).

So, if you want to read a string of 20 bytes, do this:

```
DataReader reader = new DataReader(tcpClient.InputStream);
await reader.LoadAsync(20);
string data = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
```

If you want to read a string *up to* 20 bytes, do this:

```
DataReader reader = new DataReader(tcpClient.InputStream);
reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
await reader.LoadAsync(20);
string data = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
```

See this video for more info: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-580T

Note that `DataReader` does not give you message boundaries; it's just a more convenient way of waiting for and reading binary data from a stream. You still need [message framing](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/message-framing.html).

Comment: Also note that LoadAsync there with the Partial flag can return as soon as there is 1 byte available, so UnconsumedBufferLength there might be less than the total length of the string.